# Trouble using "from import" to import another .py file in the same directory(new to python)

Tags: python-3.x

learning python basics, please help!

My First file was named 'tut 23 Classes and Objects.py'

#The code was about creating a class

```
    class donars:

    def __init__(self, name , blood_group , age , donatable_organ):
        self.name = name
        self.blood_group = blood_group
        self.age = age
        self.donatable_organ = donatable_organ
```

Now I named another one, 'tut 1.py' for importing the file and a class in it...

```
from 'tut 23 Classes and Objects.py' import donars

donar1 = donars("xyz", "etc", "etc" , "etc")

print(donar1)
```

The error says "invalid syntax before from (which could be the single quotes), but how should i call the file name then?..it doesn't recognise!

```
enter code here
```

Comment: in general its a bad habit to name files with spaces in them. name it tut_classes.py. Also you dont need to mention .py so just say from tu23clasandobjects import *

Comment: from-imports take "names", not strings as their first "argument". Therefore, to be importable, your file needs to be called like an identifier (a variable) could be. In addition, you don't use the `.py` part of the file here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problems with import my files too, resolved the issue appendding a path to import them

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/my/files/')
import my_files
```

and just a tip, as Bounty Collector said, don't use spaces, normally we use _, spaces can cause a lot of problems, and generally request use of scape ('\') to be understood

Comment: Thanks, but this way, I can't use the From-import command, and the tutorial that I watch, requires to do so..